# Why will SQLAlchemy import in Jupyter Notebook, but not in a virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import SQLAlchemy in the interpreter.

```
% pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
greenlet   2.0.1
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.6.3
SQLAlchemy 1.4.45
wheel      0.38.4
```

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

```
>>> import SQLAlchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLAlchemy'
```

```
>>> import  sqlalchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

I tried uninstalling SQLAlchemy, deactivating the virtual environment, reactivating the virtual environment, and upgrading pip. This did nothing. I still have the same error.

Comment: pypi package is called `SQLAlchemy` but actual import is `sqlalchemy`

Comment: This didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it for historical reasons the distribution name, ie. on PyPi, is not always the same as the import name.  Confusing but the way it is.  This doesn't just affect SQLAlchemy but a lot of libraries have this issue.

```
$ ve/bin/pip install SQLAlchemy
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy in ./ve/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.4.43)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in ./ve/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from SQLAlchemy) (2.0.0.post0)
```

```
Python 3.10.3 (main, Apr 22 2022, 11:37:53) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SQLAlchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLAlchemy'
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive just use sqlalchemywith lowercase.

```
import sqlalchemy
```

Tutorial with basic use:
https://towardsdatascience.com/sqlalchemy-python-tutorial-79a577141a91